# How to automatically subscribe a user to a public calendar in Windows Live Calendar?

Tags: windows, calendar, subscriptions

I have a public calendar on my site and want to provide the users a link that automatically subscribe them to this calendar on their Windows Live Calendar.

Been looking for info and couldn't find anything, just the way of doing this manually inside Windows Live Calendar.

Do you know if there is a way of doing this?
Thank you